# Connecting to SQL Server Named Instance

Tags: sql-server, remote-server, named-instance

I have a default instance of sqlserver running on my server. I installed a additional name instance. I can remote into the default instance from SSMS just fine but I cant connect to the named instance.

When I try ti enable TCP/IP for the named instance on port 1433 it does not let me start the named instance. I have to disable the TCP/IP and restart to get the instance to run again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More than likely, the default instance is already using port 1433. Try another port.

Comment: @R.Richards If I change to another port do I have to specify in SSMS on my local machine that the named instance has to connect under this port number. Or does this happen automatically?

Comment: If you connect with the named instance *name* (servername\instancename), you should be fine, and connect without any extra work. If you are using an IP address, then you will have to specify the port number too.

Comment: Note that the servername\instancename form requires the SQL Browser service to be running an UDP 1434 to be open.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks. I have that configured and its working nicely.